# Handling at least 200 Concurrent requests per second for a Laravel REST API with NGINX

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, nginx, pgbouncer

I have developed a REST API with laravel 8 and configured the backend with PostgreSQL/PostGIS. My main aim is to handle atleast 200 concurrent requests per second for the API which should return the result within a second for all 200 concurrent requests. I have listed the configurations as follows but still I could not achieve 200 concurrent requests per second but could get the results in 3 seconds.

**Technical Workflow**

NGINX 1.18.0 -> PHP-FPM -> Laravel 8 -> PGBouncer -> PostgreSQL 12/PostGIS 2.4

**AWS Server** - M6G.8X Large

**Operating System** - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**NGINX Configuration**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

# Load module section
load_module "modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so";
load_module "modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so";

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;

        client_body_timeout 12;
        client_header_timeout 12;
        keepalive_requests 2000;
        send_timeout 10;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

**PHP-FPM Configuration**

> Tried with static, dynamic and ondemand modes

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5200
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s
pm.max_requests = 2000
request_terminate_timeout = 600
```

**PGBouncer Configuration**

> Tried with session, transaction and statement modes

```
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 50000
default_pool_size = 50
reserve_pool_size = 25
reserve_pool_timeout = 3
server_lifetime = 300
server_idle_timeout = 15
server_connect_timeout = 5
server_login_retry = 2
```

**PostgreSQL Configuration**

```
shared_buffers = 32GB
effective_cache_size = 96GB
work_mem = 33MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
min_wal_size = 512MB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 1000
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
max_worker_processes = 32
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 16
max_parallel_workers = 32
parallel_setup_cost = 1000.0
parallel_tuple_cost = 0.1
min_parallel_table_scan_size = 100MB
min_parallel_index_scan_size = 5MB
parallel_leader_participation = on
```

The Laravel REST API is accessing DB for below needs.

> 1. SELECT statement of accessing a postgres function to get the output which is marked as PARALLEL SAFE
> 2. INSERT statement to add a new record in a functional table
> 3. INSERT statement to add a new record in an audit table

Even with th above configurations I could get only 65-70 requests/sec throughput while checking from jmeter for 200 parallel requests and the requests completing within 3 seconds. The API responds on an average within 300-400 ms while checking in Postman. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Find the bottleneck and work on it. That might require *profiling* your application.

Comment: I am not sure on where the bottleneck is available in the workflow. It seems the pgbouncer and postgresql is configured to handle at least 1000 requests in parallel. I could see the number of active processes in PHP-FPM status is always between 79-85 where I think the issue persists but I am not 100% sure on this. Also, I believe even postgresql could handle atleast 500 parallel connections without pgbouncer.

Comment: I would more focus on the PHP code and only worry about the rest once you have made sure you have exhausted and gains there.  Try measuring the various parts of the code (which is probably more relevant in the question than what you currently post), especially the SQL parts.

Comment: Okay I will check the PHP code for any bottlenecks. Thanks.

Comment: It all really depends what each request does and how well they can be parallelised. 200 concurrent connections on any modern DBMS is something that can be easily handled but it also depends what queries are done on those connections, and how you process the data afterwards. Also is it a hard requirement to handle all these requests on a single server? You might get better performance if you downgrade your server and just run more of them. It's good to try to get as much as you can from a single instance but at some point you're spending more time micro-optimizing than actually coding.

Comment: There's no saying how cacheable things are. You could apply Varnish if the responses do not vary greatly or don't change much in time/between users. Furthermore, make sure you run with `opcache.validate_timestamps` set to Off.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen...The issue was with the PHP code in which audit table record insertion had AccessShareLock in Postgres DB which delayed the response thereby degrading the throughput. Please let me know any best practices for handling DB audit tables and log tables. Thanks.